# Implementing a hasNext function in a C++ linked list

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to write a function to see whether or not there are more nodes to search through in the linked list, and what I have so far gives me a seg fault. Any ideas on what I need to change?

Iterator class:

```
bool Iterator::hasNext(){

  Node* temp = current->getNext();

  if(temp == NULL){

  return(false);

  }

  else{

  return(true);

 }
```

List Class:

```
    void List::addFirst(void* obj)
 {


    Node* newNode = new Node(obj);
    newNode->setNext(head);
    head = newNode;


 }
```

Node Class:

```
 Node* Node::getNext()
 {

      return(next);


  }
```

Main class:

```
    List list1;

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    list1.addFirst(stars[i]);
}

Iterator itr(&list1);

while(itr.hasNext()) {

    std::cout << ((char*)itr.get()->getItem())
              << std::endl;
    itr.advance();
}
```

Comment: There's nothing that would cause a segfault in the code you posted. Please give us code that we can actually use to reproduce the problem, especially `getNext()`.

Comment: what is the implemntation of getNext() ?!!!

Comment: Is `current` a non-NULL pointer and pointing to a valid Node object?  If not, trying to dereference it (via the -> operator) will probably segfault.

Comment: Sorry about that, I added as much code as it would let me now. FYI the iterator class has private variables List* list and Node* current that are declared but not initialized.

Comment: If you want to delete this post, you can do so with by clicking "delete" below the body of the question.

Comment: Do you assign Node::next to null in Node constructor?

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure about it but you can 
Try

```
//directly accessing the next and comparing
return if(current->getNext() == NULL)
```

directly without storing it in a separate temp node .